# Query to get the question with most answers

Tags: sql

There are 2 tables
Questions & Answers
Each question will have multiple answers

I want to write a query such that
"List all the questions and ordered by maximum number of answers"

So the question with max answer appear first, followed by 2nd question with most answer

I am writing like this

```
select questions.id from questions inner join answers
on questions.id = answers.question_id
order by max(comments.id)
```

Comment: what's `comments.id` ?

Comment: Please share schema for your database

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend your query by grouping the answers by question and order by the answer count descending. Here you go:

```
select questions.id, count(*) as AnswerCount 
from questions 
inner join answers on questions.id = answers.question_id
group by questions.id
order by count(*) desc
```

Comment: The query not return questions without answers, you can use `left join` and `coalesce` to get it

Answer (score 0):

Use the **GROUP BY** keyword:

In this solution we join the two tables and group the answers by the `question_id`, after that you order it by the `CountOfAnswers`.

```
SELECT COUNT(question_id) as CountOfAnswers, questions.id as QuestionId
FROM answers JOIN questions 
WHERE answers.question_id == questions.id 
GROUP BY question_id 
ORDER BY CountOfAnswers DESC
```

This solution is the same as above, except for you get only the `question_id` as result and not the count of the answers for each question.

```
SELECT questions.id as QuestionId 
FROM answers JOIN questions 
WHERE answers.question_id == questions.id 
GROUP BY question_id 
ORDER BY COUNT(question_id) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers suggested, GroupBy will work but you won't get all the questions back since they all perform inner join. To get all questions back even those without an answer use this;

```
SELECT q.id, q.title, q.body, COUNT(a.question_id) as answer_count
FROM questions as q 
LEFT JOIN answers as a on q.id = a.question_id 
GROUP BY q.id
ORDER BY answer_count DESC
```